# Enabling caching for GWT RPC asynchronous calls

Tags: gwt, caching, local-storage

I'm thinking of introducing some kind of caching mechanism (like HTML5 local storage) to avoid frequent RPC calls whenever possible. I would like to get feedback on how caching can be introduced in the below piece of code without changing much of the architecture (like using gwt-dispatch).

```java
void getData() {

    /* Loading indicator code skipped */

    /* Below is a gwt-maven plugin generated singleton for SomeServiceAsync */
    SomeServiceAsync.Util.getInstance().getDataBySearchCriteria(searchCriteria, new AsyncCallback<List<MyData>>() {

        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            /* Loading indicator code skipped */
            Window.alert("Problem : " + caught.getMessage());
        }

        public void onSuccess(List<MyData> dataList) {
            /* Loading indicator code skipped */
        }
    });
}
```

One way I can think of to deal with this is to have a custom MyAsyncCallback class defining onSuccess/onFailure methods and then do something like this -

```java
void getData() {

    AsyncCallback<List<MyData>> callback = new MyAsyncCallback<List<MyData>>;

    // Check if data is present in cache
    if(cacheIsPresent)
        callback.onSuccess(dataRetrievedFromCache);
    else
    //  Call RPC and same as above and of course, update cache wherever appropriate
}
```

Apart from this, I had one more question. What is the maximum size of storage available for LocalStorage for popular browsers and how do the browsers manage the LocalStorage for different applications / URLs? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to add a [delegate class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) which handles the caching. The delegate class could look like this:

```java
public class Delegate {

  private static SomeServiceAsync service = SomeServiceAsync.Util.getInstance();

  private List<MyData> data;

  public static void getData(Callback callback) {
    if (date != null) {
      callback.onSuccess(data);
    } else {
      service.getData(new Callback() {
        public onSuccess(List<MyData> result) {
          data = result;
          callback.onSuccess(result);
      });
    }
  }

}
```

Of course this is a crude sample, you have to refine the code to make it reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I did take too long to decide on using hash maps to cache results.

My strategy was not to use a singleton hashmap, but a singleton common objects class storing static instances of cache. I did not see the reason to load a single hashmap with excessive levels of hashtree branching.

**Reduce the amount of hash resolution**

If I know that the objects I am dealing with is Employee, Address, Project, I would create three static hashes

```java
final static private Map<Long, Employee> employeeCache =
  new HashMap<Long, Employee>();
final static private Map<Long, Address> addressCache =
 new HashMap<Long, Address>();
final static private Map<String name, Project> projectCache =
 new HashMap<String name, Project>();

public static void putEmployee(Long id, Employee emp){
  employeeCache.put(id, emp);
}
public static Employee getEmployee(Long id){
  return employeeCache.get(id);
}

public static void putEmployee(Long id, Address addr){
  addressCache.put(id, addr);
}
public static Address getEmployee(Long id){
  return addressCache.get(id);
}

public static void putProject(String name, Address addr){
  projectCache.put(name, addr);
}
public static Address getProject(String name){
  return projectCache.get(name);
}
```

Putting it all in a single map would be hairy. The principle of efficient access and storage of data is - the more information you have determined about the data, the more you should exploit segregating that data using that information you have. It would reduce the levels of hash resolution required to access the data. Not to mention all the risky and indefinite type casting that would need to be done.

**Avoid hashing if you can**

If you know that you always have a single value of CurrentEmployee and NextEmployee,
avoid storing them in the hash of Employee. Just create static instances

```
Employee CurrentEmployee, NextEmployee;
```

That would avoid needing any hash resolution at all.

**Avoid contaminating the global namespace**

And if possible, keep them as class instances rather than static instances, to avoid contaminating the global namespace.

Why avoid contaminating the global namespace? Because, more than one class would inadvertently use the same name causing untold number of bugs due to global namespace confusion.

**Keep the cache nearest to where it is expected or used**

If possible, if the cache is mainly for a certain class, keep the cache as a class instance within that class. And provide an eventbus event for any rare instance that another class would need to get data from that cache.

So that you would have an expectable pattern

```
ZZZManager.getZZZ(id);
```

**Finalise the cache if possible**,

otherwise/and privatise it by providing putters and getters. Do not allow another class to inadvertently re-instantiate the cache, especially if one day your class becomes a general utility library. Also putters and getters have the opportunity to validate the request to avoid a request from wiping out the cache or pushing the app into an Exception by directly presenting the cache with keys or values the cache is unable to handle.

**Translating these principles into Javascript local storage**

The GWT page says

> Judicious use of naming conventions can help with processing storage data. For example, in a web app named MyWebApp, key-value data associated with rows in a UI table named Stock could have key names prefixed with MyWebApp.Stock.

Therefore, supplementing the HashMap in your class, with rather crude code,

```java
public class EmployeePresenter {
  Storage empStore = Storage.getLocalStorageIfSupported();
  HashMap<Long, Employee> employeeCache;

  public EmployeePresenter(){
    if (empStore==null) {
      employeeCache = new HashMap<Employee>();
    }
  }

  private String getPrefix(){
    return this.getClass()+".Employee";
    //return this.getClass().getCanonicalName()+".Employee";
  }

  public Employee putEmployee(Long id, Employee employee)
    if (empStore==null) {
      stockStore.setItem(getPrefix()+id, jsonEncode(employee));
      return;
    }
    employeeCache.put(id, employee);
  }

  public Employee getEmployee(Long id)
    if (empStore==null) {
      return (Employee) jsonDecode(Employee.class, stockStore.getItem(getPrefix()+id));
    }
    return employeeCache(id);
  }
}
```

Since, the localstore is string based only, I am presuming that you will be writing your own json encoder decoder. On the other hand, why not write the json directly into the store the moment you receive it from the callback?

**Memory constraints?**

I cannot profess expertise in this question but I predict the answer for hashmaps to be the maximum memory constrained by the OS on the browser. Minus all the memory that is already consumed by the browser, plugins and javascript, etc, etc overhead.

For HTML5 local storage the GWT page says

"LocalStorage: 5MB per app per browser. According to the HTML5 spec, this limit can be increased by the user when needed; however, only a few browsers support this."

"SessionStorage: Limited only by system memory"

Comment: HTML5 local storage saves data unencrypted in string form in the regular browser cache. It is not secure storage. It should not be used for sensitive data, such as social security numbers, credit card numbers, logon credentials, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using gwt-dispath an easy solution here is to cache the gwt-dispatch Response objects agains the Request objects as a key in a Map. Its easy to implement and type agnostic. You will need to override Request - equals() method to see if the Request is already in the cache. If yes return Response from cache otherwise hit the server with a call.

IMO - LocalStorage is not a necessity here if all you need is in session cache for performance. Local Storage only a must for offline apps.

You may look into this - http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/caching-batching-dispatcher-for-gwt-dispatch/

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, I'm *not* exploring gwt-dispatch for this.

Comment: Even without gwt-dispatch you can very well apply the approach to your code. In such a case use a HashMap to store searchCriteria objects as key and the ListData objects as values. Such an approach is quite generic and will scale well to cache varied types of data requests vs. results. You may choose to use a Cacheable vs. Result interface of your own to create a generic system.

Comment: Yes, but this question wasn't about how the cache can be designed/implemented. It was more about what Adrian. B answered. Thanks anyway.